# Speedup database on webpage viewcount

Tags: mongodb, server, database

How to optimize the viewcount calculation on mongoDB?

We have an huge number of almost static pages apart from the viewcount. We've tried to calculate it from log without triggering DB operation when users are viewing the webpage, and process the log during easy hours. Is a more elegant way to optimize this viewcount calculation?

Comment: Can you give a better sense of your schema? It's hard for anyone to optimize something they don't understand

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.ca/analytics/) or something similar to do it for you. Plus you'd get a whole lot of other useful metrics.